# Displaying popup menu of list item in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view with list item, rendered with ListTile widget, now I want during long press, to display a popup at the exact location of the list item, so far I have this:

```
showMenu(
  context: context,
  position: RelativeRect.fill,
  items: [
    PopupMenuItem(child: Text('View')),
    PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Delete')),
  ],
);
```

I believe the position determines where it will be displayed but now, how do I get that position.

Answer (score 1):

To get the position of the widget just use a global key and then get its position in onTapDown and in longPress use the position to display.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const HomeWidget());
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeWidget> createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  var containerKey = GlobalKey();
  var tapPositon = const Offset(0, 0);

  Size get sizeQuery => MediaQuery.of(context).size;

  void getTapPosition(TapDownDetails tapDownDetails) {
    final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    setState(() {
      tapPositon = renderBox.globalToLocal(tapDownDetails.globalPosition);
    });
  }

  void showContextMenu() async {
    await showMenu(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
          tapPositon.dx,
          tapPositon.dy,
          sizeQuery.width - tapPositon.dx,
          sizeQuery.height - tapPositon.dy,
        ),
        items: TapMenuItemEnum.values
            .map((e) => PopupMenuItem(
                  child:  Text(e.toName()),
                  onTap: () => onTapItem(e),
                ))
            .toList()
        // items: [
        // PopupMenuItem(
        //   child: const Text('View'),
        //   onTap: () => onTapItem(TapMenuItemEnum.view),
        // ),
        //   PopupMenuItem(
        //     child: const Text('Delete'),
        //     onTap: () => onTapItem(TapMenuItemEnum.delete),
        //   ),
        // ],
        );
  }

  void onTapItem(TapMenuItemEnum tap) {
    print(tap);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Row(),
          GestureDetector(
            key: containerKey,
            onLongPress: showContextMenu,
            onTapDown: getTapPosition,
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('tap', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum TapMenuItemEnum {
  delete,
  view,
}

extension MemberTapTapMenuItemEnum on TapMenuItemEnum {
  String toName() {
    return describeEnum(this);
  }
}
```